# ACTION_SEND not share URLs, there is no explanation

Tags: android, url, android-intent, share

It seems to be an easy procedure, but is giving me a huge headache.

I have in my app a button to share the URL of the post you are on the screen. The URL is stored in the variable strUrl.

I do all the standard procedure:

```
Intent I = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
I.setType("text/plain");
I.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Uri.parse(strUrl));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(I,"Share with..."));
```

By clicking the button, the menu usually features Android applications to choose which one to share.
Choose those who have interest: Twitter, Facebook, Email, etc ...

However, when you open the screen app, Facebook for example, the screen again post without containing the URL that I tried to share through my application.
I tried writing a normal message, but this did not appear.

```
I.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "some text here");
```

I realize that something is very wrong. The problem is repeated in all the applications that I try to share through my application.

I'm testing on Android 2.3 and 4.2.2

I ask here apologize for my English level, I'm Brazilian and I'm using Google translator to take this course.

Comment: `EXTRA_TEXT` is definitely supposed to be a string, not a `Uri`.

Comment: Also, for what it is worth, this sample app demonstrates both sending and receiving `ACTION_SEND`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Introspection/FauxSender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, strUrl);
```

Comment: I got that URL was shared with Facebook simply removing the
`Uri.parse(strUrl)`
and leaving only
`I.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, strUrl);`
But it did not work on Twitter.

Comment: Ready. Twitter actually hangs for a while, and then back to work displaying the shared URL. Google+, HootSuite and Gmail also worked after a while caught.
Now I just need a way to filter these applications appear to share the list is long and vague.
+1
thanks